# how to pluck or select values from a database and return separate arrays for each record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, activerecord

i have a model History(data:text) and the data is an serialized array

I want to render the all of the saved histories as json; however calling the records forces them into 1 array when I need each history to be contained in a separate hash.

When I call:

> History.limit(1).pluck(:data)

everything is fine because I get 1 array:

```
[{"miners"=>{},
  "stats"=>
   {"amtDue"=>422770422,
    "amtPaid"=>0,
    "hash"=>18,
    "identifier"=>"global",
    "invalidShares"=>1,
    "lastHash"=>1515350526,
    "timeout"=>1515350582003,
    "totalHashes"=>7107814,
    "txnCount"=>0,
    "validShares"=>9598},
  "ticker"=>
   {"base"=>"XMR",
    "change"=>"-5.01749443",
    "price"=>"396.34459617",
    "target"=>"USD",
    "volume"=>"24647.97760706"},
  "timestamp"=>1515350523}]
```

However, when I call 2 or more records they are contained in 1 array which won't work for my needs:

> History.limit(2).pluck(:data)

```
[{"miners"=>{},
  "stats"=>
   {"amtDue"=>422770422,
    "amtPaid"=>0,
    "hash"=>18,
    "identifier"=>"global",
    "invalidShares"=>1,
    "lastHash"=>1515350526,
    "timeout"=>1515350582003,
    "totalHashes"=>7107814,
    "txnCount"=>0,
    "validShares"=>9598},
  "ticker"=>
   {"base"=>"XMR",
    "change"=>"-5.01749443",
    "price"=>"396.34459617",
    "target"=>"USD",
    "volume"=>"24647.97760706"},
  "timestamp"=>1515350523},
 {"miners"=>{},
  "stats"=>
   {"amtDue"=>422770422,
    "amtPaid"=>0,
    "hash"=>4,
    "identifier"=>"global",
    "invalidShares"=>1,
    "lastHash"=>1515353143,
    "timeout"=>1515353179152,
    "totalHashes"=>7125334,
    "txnCount"=>0,
    "validShares"=>9628},
  "ticker"=>
   {"base"=>"XMR",
    "change"=>"3.74386788",
    "price"=>"405.10595848",
    "target"=>"USD",
    "volume"=>"25292.54683583"},
  "timestamp"=>1515353103}]
```

How do I get data for each history in a separate hash? Here's my controller, I want to render the arrays as json:

```
def inquiry
@step = inquiry params[:step]
@n = inquiry_params[:n]

if @n.present?
  @history = History.limit(@n).pluck[:data]
  render :json => @history
else
....
end

 def inquiry_params
    accessible = [:step, :n]
    params.permit(accessible)
  end
```

edit:
I'm now calling :

> @history = Hash[History.limit(@n).pluck(:data).flatten.map{ |el| [el] }].flatten

I get the desired format; however there is an unwanted "null" that I don't understand where it comes from or how to get rid.

```
[{"miners"=>["b9aeff80-e16d-4af6-b675-9f218eff8077"],
  "stats"=>
   {"amtDue"=>422770422,
    "amtPaid"=>0,
    "hash"=>28,
    "identifier"=>"global",
    "invalidShares"=>1,
    "lastHash"=>1515435268,
    "timeout"=>1515435354059,
    "totalHashes"=>9370026,
    "txnCount"=>0,
    "validShares"=>11999},
  "ticker"=>
   {"base"=>"XMR",
    "change"=>"1.18426262",
    "price"=>"383.96558958",
    "target"=>"USD",
    "volume"=>"24605.93213606"},
  "timestamp"=>1515435302},
 nil,
 {"miners"=>["b9aeff80-e16d-4af6-b675-9f218eff8077"],
  "stats"=>
   {"amtDue"=>422770422,
    "amtPaid"=>0,
    "hash"=>28,
    "identifier"=>"global",
    "invalidShares"=>1,
    "lastHash"=>1515435467,
    "timeout"=>1515435505244,
    "totalHashes"=>9374886,
    "txnCount"=>0,
    "validShares"=>12005},
  "ticker"=>
   {"base"=>"XMR",
    "change"=>"0.52934940",
    "price"=>"383.31067636",
    "target"=>"USD",
    "volume"=>"24591.95015563"},
  "timestamp"=>1515435422},
 nil]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but it's possible to use [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) like this:

```
2.5.0 :001 > z = [ {:s=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}}, {:t=>{:c=>3, :d=>4}} ]
   => [{:s=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}}, {:t=>{:c=>3, :d=>4}}] 
2.5.0 :002 > z.map{ |el| [el] }
   => [[{:s=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}}], [{:t=>{:c=>3, :d=>4}}]]
```

In your case it should then be `History.limit(2).pluck(:data).map{ |el| [el] }`

**EDIT:** By calling [compact](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/compact) you will have your result-array with all the `nil` values removed like this:

```
2.5.0 :003 > x = [{a: {b: 1, c: 2}}, nil]
    => [{:a=>{:b=>1, :c=>2}}, nil]
2.5.0 :004 > x.compact
    => [{:a=>{:b=>1, :c=>2}}]
```

Comment: How would that work in the case of my code?

if z  = History.limit(2).pluck(:data)

Comment: In my case z is initially an array. Each History record is an array.

Comment: Indeed, made an edit now - changed the `z` variable to array of hashes and added every hash inside this array into subarray so it would be possible to extract them as JSON. Is this what you kept in mind?

Comment: You can use `compact` to remove the `nil` values from array- check the edited answer.